# Cake bake model generation (hasOne vs hasMany)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to get the 'cake bake' console command to generate 2 Models with a belongsTo/hasOne relationship (from the database schema) and it keeps generating a belongsTo/hasMany two-way relationship.

I am following the [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/81/belongsTo) guide on these definitions for the column name conventions ('user_id' in Profile, 'profile_id' in User) but, like I said, 'cake bake' keeps getting it wrong.  Is 'cake bake' capable of determining the difference between hasOne and hasMany?  Does anyone have a simple MySQL schema example where this is working? I'm using CakePHP 1.3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hasOne and hasMany relationships are identical from an SQL schema perspective, the difference is simply that there's an artificial restriction on the number of related records (1). `bake` can't tell the difference. If you're using the interactive process, it should suggest the more common hasMany relationship first, and the hasOne alternative second.

Comment: so I'll just use the interactive process to set that relationship, thanks!

Comment: @phife Or you could, you know, simply edit the resulting model and change `hasMany` to `hasOne`… :)

Comment: ha, yeah!  My goal is to get the command to do it and understand why it isn't working.  I appreciate the help!